# Looking for title of novel about future Earth with colonies

Tags: story-identification

Hopefully someone can help me identify the title and maybe the author of a science fiction novel I read back in the late 1970's - although I suspect book was at least several years older. In the book, Earth had a planet-wide government similar to that of the United States: president, legislature, etc. It also had a number of colonies, although I don't remember if these were within the solar system or on planets around other stars. As I remember, the colonies had surpassed Earth, and the President was trying to determine how best to bring the planet up to speed with the colonies. In the end,

> the president concludes that the government of Earth makes the planet too slow to change. He suspends the constitution and declares himself dictator.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like Asimov's "[Mother Earth](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56133)". The President provokes the outer worlds into war, after which they set up a permanent blockade of the solar system, forcing  Earth back on its own resources, compelling her to make reforms which have hitherto been rejected in favour of demands that the Outer Worlds accept more immigrants.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I don't remember an actual war.